# How to make a popup window with an image SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, popup

I was wondering how to make a popup window similar to this example:

[image]

The origin window is full of buttons that when is selected will then pull up the image I desire to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply create a reusable `UIView` component and everything you need as a subview, such as a `UIImageView` for your image, a `UILabel` or a `UIButton` in the top right. Here is the process to show it:

1. Create a `UIView` that takes up the full screen, make it black, and maybe 0.5 alpha.
2. Create another `UIView` which is your primary pop-up view, make it slightly smaller than the previous view, but make sure both of these views are subviews of the parent subview.
3. Add the desired elements on to the pop-up view as subviews, I would even suggest creating a `UIView` subclass if you plan to use this a lot.
4. To present the pop-up, make sure both views are set to `hidden = true` when created and so that when a button is selected, you can set them to `hidden = false`
5. If you would like them to be animated, simply start them off with `alpha = 0.0` and use something like UIView's `animateWithDuration` and set the pop-up view to `alpha = 1.0`

There is a lot of little details you can change to cater to your needs, but this is the basic structure on how to accomplish your goal.

Check out UIView animation methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108).